# How to encrypt Messages in Django Channels

Tags: python, django, django-channels

Well i have gone through the tutorials of django channels. But the is a loop hole since there is no explanation on how to encrypt a message in django channel.  Lets say  i have a chat models bellow

```
class ChatThread(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(null=True,max_length=200)
class chat(models.Model):
    thread_id=models.ForeignKey(ChatThread,null=True)
    messages=models.TextField()
```

I want the object of chat to be encrypted when created and decrypted on request within the application. Please i am new to python, so be kind with your explanations. Thanks I am using postgres data base

Comment: Do you want the message to be encrypted in the database?

Comment: yes sir, so if any one hacks my database, they will not be able to read the file. Unless it is decripted

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: I am using postgress database

Comment: I use [django-encrypted-model-fields](https://pypi.org/project/django-encrypted-model-fields/)